Hide Menu Link and Children to Logged Out Users in WordPress
I have a membership website, and I would like to show a menu item (and its sub-links) only to logged-in users in WordPress.
I'm using the code below, but it only hides the parent link and does not include the child sub-links (they are still visible, and I would like to hide them).
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'hide_menu_conditional', 10, 2);
function hide_menu_conditional($items, $args) {
        // Check if the USer is logged in
        foreach($items as $key => $item) {
            if(is_user_logged_in()) {
                if($item->title == 'Members Area') {
                    unset($items[$key]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    return $items;
}

What can I do to hide the parent link and its children?
Thank you

Let's assume my menu structure is as follows, and I want to hide the Prestations menu item along with its child items:
- Prestations
  - Logout
  - Sample Page
- Product
- Contact

First, run var_dump($item) before the if() statement to identify the ID of the parent menu item (Prestations). In my case, the ID is "54".
Add $item->menu_item_parent === "54" in the if statement with an or operator, so the statement will be true for the parent menu and for all it's
children, all of them will be removed by the unset function.

function hide_menu_conditional($items, $args){
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

        // echo "<pre>";
        // var_dump($item);
        // echo "</pre>";

        // Check if the User is logged in
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            if ( $item->title == 'Prestations' || $item->menu_item_parent === "54" ) {
                unset($items[$key]);
            }
        }
        
    }
    return $items;
}


This is my answer for the Question: What can I do to hide the parent
link and its children?

I hope this is helpful. Please feel free to reach out if you have any questions or need further clarification.

I think you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/ plugin and it will should do what you want without coding.
Thank You! :)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
